# Facebook feed with music attachment

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hey all, im trying to post a facebook food using the Javascript SDK with an .mp3 file attachment, my code is the following:

for initializing the facebook api:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId  : _cfg.fbAppId,
      status : false,
      cookie : false,
      xfbml  : true
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

and then i have the following code to send the feed:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  attachment: {
    media:[{
      'type' : 'music',
      'src' : 'http://media.*****.com/files/test.mp3',
      'title' : 'this is a test mp3 file',
      'artist' : 'test artist',
      'album' : 'Test Album'
    }]
  },
  display: 'page'
});
```

when the dialog opens it just shows me

> type 'music' is not allowed

any ideas how to solve this issue? all i want is to be able to post the feed with the mp3 file so friends can see the feed in the news feed and listen to the file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`music` isn't an allowed type. I think `mp3` is:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  attachment: {
    media:[{
      'type' : 'mp3',
      'src' : 'http://media.*****.com/files/test.mp3',
      'title' : 'this is a test mp3 file',
      'artist' : 'test artist',
      'album' : 'Test Album'
    }]
  },
  display: 'page'
});
```

Comment: i tried with type: 'mp3' and it gives me the same error as with type: 'music'

Comment: Lol, Facebook was having a bad day.